# is it possible to create azure build pipelines using terraform code?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I want to Create Azure Build pipelines using Terraform code, but not able to find any proper documentation on this. Is it possible ?

I tried terraform documentation, expecting some documentation or video guide how to create Azure build pipelines using terraform code

Comment: I don't see it in the list of supported services on this page, do you? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs

Comment: The answer is no, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to create azure build pipelines using terraform code?

The answer is impossible.

Hashicorp doesn't have a [terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/search/providers?namespace=hashicorp) for Azure DevOps now.

If you check the [azurerm provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs), only [azurerm_data_factory_pipeline](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_pipeline) is available, no Azure DevOps build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Azure DevOps provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs) From Microsoft. It does contain a resource for [build definitions](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/resources/build_definition) but you will need to pass it the path to an existing YAML file, you can't create the YAML from Terraform.

If you have a "templated" YAML then you could create a process that commits the YAML to a repo then use Terraform to set up the definition.